# jquery regex - escape html chars and back

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I have some html code that needs to be escaped and then later on converted back to html ... the code i have till now is ...

```
var entityMap = {
                            "&": "&amp;",
                            "<": "&lt;",
                            ">": "&gt;",
                            '"': '&quot;',
                            "'": '&#39;',
                            "/": '&#x2F;',
                             "\n" : '<br>' 
                          };
                     var entityMaprev = {
                           "&amp;" :"&" ,
                            "&lt;": "<",
                            "&gt;":">" ,
                            '&quot;':'"' ,
                            '&#39;': "'",
                            '&#x2F;': "/",
                            '<br>' : "\n"  
                          };   
                          function escapeHtml(string) {
                            return String(string).replace( /[&<>"'\/]|[\n]/g, function (s) {
                              return entityMap[s];
                            });
                          }
                          function revescapeHtml(string) {
                            return String(string).replace( /[&amp;]|[&lt;]|[&gt;]|[&quot;]|[&#39;]|[&#x2F;]|[<br>]/g, function (s) {
                              return entityMaprev[s];
                            });
                          }
```

the function escapeHtml(string) works perfect ...

where i am having problem is in the  function revescapeHtml it keeps showing as undefined ? is my regex correct in   function revescapeHtml ?

thanks

Comment: First you should remove the square brackets around the entities. Currently it will only match one character

Comment: I suggest to do this on the server.

Comment: @Rhumborl can you post the code i am horrible at regex....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your regex:

```
function revescapeHtml(string) {
  return String(string).replace( /(&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|&quot;|&#39;|&#x2F;|<br>)/g, function (s) {
    return entityMaprev[s];
  });
}
```

`revescapeHtml("&amp;")` returns `&`.

BTW: if you want to return `"\n"` as string as is, adjust your array aswell: `'<br>' : "\\n"`